# Create dynamic legend on R Shiny Leaflet Maps, Error: 'colors' and 'labels' must be of the same length

Tags: r, arrays, shiny, leaflet, legend

I have been struggling in creating a dynamic maps legend in R shiny Leaflet Maps.
The idea is to have a template code so whenever the data change, the map and its legend will follow. The coordinate is already able to adjust with change in data, but still have no idea how to make the legend become dynamic as well

Here is the code

test_map.csv contains list of data
`dat_map <- read.csv("data_input/test_map.csv", header = T)`

This is for the UI. where there is input to access specific data in the test_map.csv which I named it as "querymap"

```
      tabItem(tabName = "maps",
          fluidRow(
             
             sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                          selectInput("querymap","Title:",dat_map$Title),
                          strong("Description:"), textOutput("captionmap"), br(),
                          strong("Reference:"), uiOutput("referencemap"), #textOutput("reference"), 
                          em(textOutput("latestmap")), br(),
                          strong("Tags: "), verbatimTextOutput("tagsmap")),
             mainPanel(
                h2(textOutput("dinTitlemap")),
                tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Map",br(),leafletOutput("mapall")),
                   tabPanel("Table", br(), DT::dataTableOutput("dinTablemap")), 
                   tabPanel("Download", br(), downloadButton("dlTablemap", label = "Download Table"))
                )))))
```

This is the "reactive" to get data from the test_map.csv

```
    db_map <- reactive({
   filename <- dat_map$Filename[dat_map$Title == input$querymap]
   db_map <- read.csv(paste("data_input/", filename, sep = "")) %>% 
      select(-No)
   db_map})
```

And here's the output code

```
output$mapall <- renderLeaflet({
db_map <- db_map ()

  pal <- colorFactor(
     palette = c('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange','grey','green'),
     domain = db_map$kategori) #pallete for coordinate and legend color
  
  addLegendCustom <- function(map, colors, labels, sizes, opacity = 0.8){
     colorAdditions <- paste0(colors, "; width:", sizes, "px; height:", sizes, "px")
     labelAdditions <- paste0("<div style='display: inline-block;height: ",
                              sizes, "px;margin-top: 4px;line-height: ",
                              sizes, "px;'>", labels, "</div>")
     
     return(addLegend(map, title = "Category", colors = colorAdditions,
                      labels = labelAdditions, opacity = opacity, position = "bottomleft"))}
  
  leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE, minZoom = 3, maxZoom = 100), data = db_map) %>% 
     fitBounds(min(db_map$long),min(db_map$lat),max(db_map$long),max(db_map$lat)) %>%
     addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', group = "CartoDB Light") %>% 
     addCircleMarkers(
        radius = 7, 
        color = 'black',
        stroke = TRUE, weight = 1,
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        fillColor = ~pal(kategori),
     )%>%
     kategori = as.factor(db_map$kategori) %>%
     addLegendCustom(colors = ~pal, labels = db_map$kategori, sizes = c(10,10,10)) %>% #here is the problem
     })
```

**Then the error is "Error: 'colors' and 'labels' must be of the same length"**

Yes I know that it is not at the same length because the color pallette is set for 6 color, but the labels depends on how many variables in db_map$kategori. So my question is how to create same length of colors with the labels?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First, figure out how many colors you need by `numcolor = length(unique(db_map$kategori))`.  Then choose that many colors from a palette or your own manual list.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more on where should I put that in the code? is it at the pal color, or at the leaflet, or others maybe?

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as shown below.  Add more colors to your list, if necessary.

```
output$mapall <- renderLeaflet({
    db_map <- db_map()
    
    numcolor = length(unique(db_map$kategori))
    mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "black", "brown", "purple", "green", "darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "maroon", "yellow", "cyan","grey")
    pal <- mycolor[1:numcolor]  ##  this ensures that you have the same length of colors as labels
    
    # pal <- colorFactor(
    #   palette = c('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange','grey','green'),
    #   domain = db_map$kategori) #pallete for coordinate and legend color
    
.
.
.
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. But f.y.i I should make some adjustment at fill color and legend function

fillColor = mycolor[1:numcolor]

and

addLegendCustom(colors = mycolor[1:numcolor], labels = unique(db_map$kategori), sizes = sizec[1:numcolor])

Thank you for your help